# Creating a build pipeline view into a nested view in Jenkins with groovy script

Tags: plugins, view, groovy, jenkins, directory

I'd like to create build pipeline views in a folder created with Cloudbees Folder Plugin in Jenkins from script. Generation of the build pipeline view works fine with the following groovy script below, but it will be created at the top level in Jenkins:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.views.*
import au.com.centrumsystems.hudson.plugin.buildpipeline.*

restrict_trigger_to_recent = false
v = new BuildPipelineView("new_pipeline", "Pipeline", new DownstreamProjectGridBuilder("First Pipeline Job"), "10", restrict_trigger_to_recent, "", false)

Hudson.instance.addView(v)
```

I'll have to create several pipeline views, so it would be great to organize them in a folder or under a nested view, but I haven't found any solution how to enhance this groovy script to create the new view under an existing folder (or nested view).

Source of the Folder plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cloudbees-folder-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/hudson/plugins/folder/Folder.java#L21).